# Pagination in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to add pagination in Angular js.Sinch my server returns huge number of rows on each query So i am using some limit offset to get only 101 rows(required rows+1) at a time.(Building array of 20 pages ,reusing extra row value for next request.)
No- of rows per page=5
So on getting 101 rows means i can paginate upto 20 pages. Since i already have an extra row So i know there is more data left , So on next page request again am querying to get rows 101-201. But my doubt here is how to add logic in next page and previous page function and how to build next or previous set of data?

My app.js-
My 1st time request-
$scope.startingid = null;
$scope.numberofrows= 101;

```
   Api.customer.query({ productId : $scope.customer , productperiod :$scope.customerPeriod,startingid:$scope.startingid,numberofrows:$scope.numberofrows }).$promise.then(function(result) {
                        if(result){
                            if(result&&result.length==0){
                                $scope.addErrorAlert("No Customer data found with this productId and Period.", true);
                                $scope.displayPage = 'search';
                                return;
                            }
                          $scope.customerResult = result;
                          $scope.displayPage = 'drill';
                           $scope.showData();
                        }
```

// Pagination Logic-
My code is working fine if result set is small number of data. But need to implement in such a way that it can handle large number of rows as well.
 few doubts-
1. how to build the data for request 101-201. 
2. next and previous page logic

```
      $scope.paged = function (valLists,itemsPerPage)
             {
                var retVal = [];
                 for (var i = 0; i < valLists.length; i++) {
                     if (i % itemsPerPage === 0) {
                         retVal[Math.floor(i / itemsPerPage)] = [valLists[i]];
                     } else {
                         retVal[Math.floor(i / itemsPerPage)].push(valLists[i]);
                     }
                 }
                 return retVal;
             };

        $scope.pagination = function () {
                    $scope.ItemsByPage = $scope.paged( $scope.customerResult, $scope.itemsPerPage );         
                };
        $scope.showData = function( ){
            // $scope.noOfrows = 101;
             $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
             $scope.currentPage = 0;
             $scope.pagination();
             $scope.range = function() {
                    var rangeSize = 4;
                    var ps = [];
                    var start;

                    start = $scope.currentPage;
                    if ( start > $scope.pageCount()-rangeSize ) {
                      start = $scope.pageCount()-rangeSize+1;
                    }

                    for (var i=start; i<start+rangeSize; i++) {
                      ps.push(i);
                    }
                    return ps;
                  };

              $scope.prevPage = function() {
                if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
                  $scope.currentPage--;
                }
              };

              $scope.DisablePrevPage = function() {
                return $scope.currentPage === 0 ? "disabled" : "";

                //?? TODO add logic for samething as disabled next page and build table data
              };

              $scope.pageCount = function() {
                return Math.ceil($scope.customerResult.length/$scope.itemsPerPage)-1;
              };

              $scope.nextPage = function() {
                if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pageCount()) {
                  $scope.currentPage++;
                }
              };

              $scope.DisableNextPage = function() {
                  if($scope.currentPage === $scope.pageCount()){
                      if($scope.noOfrows >$scope.customerResult.length)
                          return $scope.currentPage === $scope.pageCount() ? "disabled" : ""; 
                      $scope.noOfrows =  $scope.noOfrows+ 100;
                      Api.customerReq.query({ productId : $scope.customerProduct , productperiod :$scope.customerPeriod, noOfrows:$scope.noOfrows }).$promise.then(function(result) {
                            if(result){
                                if(result&&result.length==0){
                                    return $scope.currentPage === $scope.pageCount() ? "disabled" : "";
                                    }
                                $scope.showData();// how to build all data on when i query for 101-201 data?
                            }

                  });
            }

              };

              $scope.setPage = function(n) {
                $scope.currentPage = n;
              };

            };
```

Comment: any suggestion or help will be appriciated, or else any available docs??

Comment: Do you wanna make pagination manually?

Comment: yes..any suggestion ?

Comment: I could suggest you to use a ready module, like dirPagination, very simple to use, take a look if you want: https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination